# Новое окно с крестиком

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка

На сайте https://www.citilink.ru/ при нажатии на кнопку Каталог товаров возникает окно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как (с помощью каких технологий и фитч) можно добиться открытия выпадающего окна (с помощью щелчка на кнопке) с крестиком для закрытия? Не серчайте, если что не так - я новичок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш вопрос слишком абстрактен для примеров кода, но вот вам теоретический гайд:

Сверстать блок с каталогом, как обычную страницу, по событию onclick в кнопке, вставлять в dom дерево с css свойством "position: absolute" за пределами экрана и плавно выдвигать с помощью transition. Крестик просто задвигает обратно тем же transition и удаляет блок из dom дерева.

Пример отступа от левого края, думаю этого достаточно:

```
left: 0
margin-right: /*размер сайдбара*/
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127402/discussion-on-answer-by-mryogurt----).